# How can you block a program from accessing the internet on a specific network(s)

Tags: windows, networking

Basically, I am trying to stop BitTorrent from running on my home network, as I have limited usage and don't want it to download things there.  However, I want it to run when I have my laptop in other places, since they don't have limits, and therefore I can allow Bittorrent to download freely.  Is there a program or something to do this?  I have NetLimiter but I haven't been able to use it for this.

Thanks!

Comment: other networks probably do not want people downloading unlimited either, as it could make things worse for everybody,  sometimes they rely on people being considerate, but would enforce a strict limitation even a complete stoppage, if it was used too much, which isn't ideal for them but might have to be done by them to prevent abuse by somebody that has the selfish mindset of "they don't have limits".

Answer (score 0):

Try blocking ports 6881 to 6889 TCP and UDP via your router/firewall. Not foolproof, but it will help stop bittorrent traffic on your local network without compromising your ability to use bittorrent on other networks.